# Typesetting of digits in groups of two

Tags: macros, typography

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{oldstyle}

\begin{document}
\textos{12345678}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like a command that group the digits in two and puts a `\,` space between each group, e.g.,

```
12\,34\,56\,78
```

[image: output2]

Comment: If odd number of digits do you group from left or right?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ohh! I didn't even think of this; let's just say from the left when there is an odd number of digits. `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This inserts `,` for ease of debugging, change to `\,` as required

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{oldstyle}

\def\zz#1{\textos{\xzz#1\relax\relax\relax}}
\def\xzz#1#2#3{#1#2%
\ifx\relax#3\else,\expandafter\xzz
\fi#3}
\begin{document}
\zz{12345678}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but does the command really give oldstyle numbers as output?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg it does now:-)

Comment: It is good that today is Friday.  That answer sure makes me want to `\relax`.  And the zz's are icing on the cake.